# How can you enforce XSD?

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I just started switching my old DTD over to XSD when I found out about it, and I am wondering how I can enforce the XSD with my XML files? I have seen the W3C validator out there for it, but I wish that there was a way to make the program not run in the browser if an XSD error was found. Is that possible?

Comment: Again, what language is "the program" written in?

Comment: nope, you didn't edit. After editing, you have to click "Save" ;)

Comment: @Chad I am using all of the following, PHP/XML/HTML/Javascript/XSD....But the XSD is only for checking the XML.

Comment: And **enforcing** XSD rules can only be done via a validating _parser_. What parser are you using (aka, what language/platform)?

Comment: @Metropolis, you haven't mentioned that you have an "interoperability" problem to solve.  The biggest benefit to an XSD file is that I, as a service provider, can give you, as a new client, an un-ambiguous contract that governs the format in which you must send me your data.  We can then use it to filter out any syntax problems from semantic problems.  Hope that helps you understand XSD's purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enforcing of XSD rules cannot be done directly within XML, as it is a textual file format and has not intrinsic logic or way to check itself for validity.

In order to enforce the rules, you need to use a validating parser - this parser can load the XML and XSD and check the XML for validity against the XSD. This is also true for DTDs.

Comment: So if this is the case....Is there any reason to reference the .xsd file from the .xml file?

Comment: @Metropolis - It is handy as a reference, if nothing else. You could use a parser to extract the XSD reference in order to find/get the XSD and validate against it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible using validating XML parsers, which are available for most general purpose languages.

OK, so it's PHP, then, directly from the first google hit on "validating XML PHP":

```
<?php

$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->load('./lures.xml');

if (!$xml->schemaValidate('./lures.xsd')) { 
   echo "invalid<p/>";
} 
else { 
   echo "validated<p/>"; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: sure, as soon as you tell us what language/environment are you developing for

Comment: I didnt really care so much about using a parser....I already knew that could be done. What I really was wondering is if it could be done directly from when the page loads in the browser. But thanks a lot for the example :) +1. I also did not really appreciate the "first google hit" as if I did not already look for it. I would not be here if I had not.

Comment: then you need to elaborate more. What XML are you validating? Is it part of the page content? Is it something else? Where does it come from?

Comment: Well until I put the question up....I did not think it needed that much detail. Because I guess I was not looking for a way to do it inside a language....I was asking if it could be done from a browser.

Comment: @Metropolis - browsers contain and use XML parsers. Normally they don't do validation against XSDs.

Comment: @Oded +1 And that annoys me lol.....I wish they did. I kinda figure the whole point of adding a validation file to the XML file is that you want it to be validated. Do you think this will ever change in the future?

Comment: @Metropolis - probably not. It adds quite a lot of logic for something most people don't need...